# How to restore form after login in spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security

There is form with 10 fields. When form is submitted, user should be validated.
With spring security, login is shown after submitting form. And after login form data is lost.
Is there are some easy way to keep form data? Or at least to redirect to page with that form filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should redirect to the page and with the field values by default unless you have configured spring security otherwise.
Can you post your config? 
I use the following config and works as expected. (posts the data to the action url after logging in)

```
<form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?failed=true" />
```

remember that your **form-login** config shouldn't have **default-target-url** set.